# cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'"

Tags: c#

My C# code:

```
public int printallancestor(Node root, Node key)
{
     if(root == null)
          return 0;
     if(root == key)
          return 1;
     if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key)||printallancestor(root.rightChild,key))
     {
          Console.WriteLine(root.iData);
          return 1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The following line `if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key)||printallancestor(root.rightChild,key))` from above code i get following error **cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'**. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your method:

```
printallancestor(root.leftChild,key)
```

returns an integer value, and you are trying to use it in a condition. You can only use **boolean** type in condition like you are doing now

I believe you are expecting your method to return `1` or `0` for true and false respectively, You can't do what you are doing right now in C#. You may try:

```
if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key) == 1|| ....
```

Or if you are expecting value greater than 1 to be true then :

```
if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key) > 1) // true
```

You may see: 
[|| Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR **of its bool
>   operands**. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand
>   isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of printallancestor is int.
You are using || operator which is for bool.
try

`if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key) != 0||printallancestor(root.rightChild,key) != 0)`

which should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The operator OR (||) requires two bool operands, not int.

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns `int`, but you are try to use in if condition. That's not ok. You can use with condition only `bool` type.

Try it like this;

```
if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key) == 1|| ..
```

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool
>   operands.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
 public bool printallancestor(Node root, Node key)
    {
        if(root == null)
            return false;
        if(root == key)
            return true;
        if(printallancestor(root.leftChild,key)||printallancestor(root.rightChild,key))

        {
            Console.WriteLine(root.iData);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```